# Python: Except block capturing exception that is not listed for block

Tags: python, exception

I have a function that makes a request to AWS using `boto3`, and I wish to capture any exceptions and raise one of two custom errors, depending on the `botocore.exceptions` exception that is returned. I thought I had this working, but an `except` block is catching errors that are not listed for that block.

First and foremost, I want to return the custom `AwsUnauthorizedException` for any SSO errors. This is fairly simple, and works as follows.

```py
aws_unauthorized_exceptions = (botocore.exceptions.SSOError, botocore.exceptions.SSOTokenLoadError, botocore.exceptions.UnauthorizedSSOTokenError)
...
except aws_unauthorized_exceptions as e:
    err_msg = str(e)
    details = {'aws_error_message': err_msg, **req_msg}
    raise AwsUnauthorizedException(**details) from None
```

However next I wish to return the custom `AwsBadRequestException` for any other `botocore.exceptions` exception. The trouble is, using `Exception` means that **every** other exception is caught, rather than just other `botocore.exceptions` exceptions, which isn't what I want to do at this point in my code.

So I'm using the `inspect` module and creating a tuple containing all exceptions in `botocore.exceptions`, except for those in `aws_unauthorized_exceptions`.

```py
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(botocore.exceptions):
    if inspect.isclass(obj) and obj not in aws_unauthorized_exceptions:
        aws_bad_request_exceptions = aws_bad_request_exceptions + (obj,)
...
except aws_bad_request_exceptions as e:
    err_msg = e.response['Error']['Message']
    details = {'aws_error_message': err_msg}
    raise AwsBadRequestException(**details)
```

However, when I include both `except` blocks with the block catching `aws_bad_request_exceptions` first, it still catches exceptions from `aws_unauthorized_exceptions`.

To be sure that the exception in question (`botocore.exceptions.SSOTokenLoadError` in this example) was not in the tuple `aws_bad_request_exceptions` I added the following line to the `except` block.

```py
printed(type(e) in aws_bad_request_exceptions)
```

This printed `False`.

Can anyone suggest why I'm seeing this unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Probably because of the specific exception hierarchy. You're probably catching some exceptions which are parent classes to the exceptions you don't want to catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All exceptions in botocore have a couple common superclasses: `botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError` and `botocore.exceptions.ClientError`.

Your `aws_bad_request_exceptions` tuple will end up including those superclasses, and since except clauses are matched in order, all BotoCore exceptions get matched.

Happily, exactly since botocore's errors have these superclasses, you don't need to construct that tuple at all; just catch the auth errors in a first except block, then every other boto error in another block (and other exceptions will not be caught).

```
import botocore.exceptions

try:
    ...
except (
    botocore.exceptions.SSOError,
    botocore.exceptions.SSOTokenLoadError,
    botocore.exceptions.UnauthorizedSSOTokenError,
) as auth_err:
    err_msg = str(auth_err)
    details = {'aws_error_message': err_msg, **req_msg}
    raise AwsUnauthorizedException(**details) from None
except (
    botocore.exceptions.BotoCoreError,
    botocore.exceptions.ClientError,
) as boto_err:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and for the most part you seem absolutely correct.
However, it appears that a few of the exceptions under `botocore.exception` are not subclassed from `BotoCoreError`, with `ClientError` being a notable exception (it is subclassed from `Exception`).

Comment: Ah, you're right, I just skimmed `botocore.exceptions`. Amended answer :)